# How does renaming a table in a Database work?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
RENAME TO new_table_name;
```

Does it delete the table named `table_name` and create a new table called `new_table_name`, or does it rename it right away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all renaming an object in PostgreSQL does is to change a single entry in a catalog table.

In the case of tables, this is the `relname` column in `pg_class`.

All internal references to the table are done via its “object ID”.

The exception here are functions. Function bodies are strings, and if you refer to a table by name in a function, that is not updated.